# AdSense with OpenCart

Tags: templates, opencart, ads, adsense

After hours upon hours of searching through stackoverflow and AdSense forums, i am not able to find anything to help me implement my google adsense code in my opencart template.

Originally i put the code  in the welcome module hoping it would show up on the top of each page but this did not work at all.

I found an extension called KINZA which was free but once installed, this simply outputs the javacript code on my website and not the actual ad.

My question is this: I would like to have one of my ads up top across the page and maybe one on the sidebar as a thin skyscrapper size. How would one do this ? Where in my opencart template would i implement the code ?? I do not want to spend money on an extension to get this to work. I would rather just dive in the code and paste it where it needs to be.\Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

there are 6 files that are included in every page of frontend

catalog/view/theme/your_theme/template/common/header.tpl , footer.tpl , column_left.tpl , column_right.tpl , content_top.tpl , content_bottom.tpl

you can put your code in any one of these and it should work fine

you can make a module for adsense so that you can control its layout and position from admin .... here is a guide of to make/duplicate a module at opencart forums http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=6696

Answer (score -1):

Opencart 3 onwards does not support google adsence you can not show ads just go for wordpress or any other